# What is the MacOS equivalent of Alt + Enter on IntelliJ?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I recently switched to programming on a Mac and I don't know any of the keyboard shortcuts for IntelliJ.

Comment: You might quite like this reference card: https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf

Answer (score 1):

> What is the MacOS equivalent of Alt + Enter on IntelliJ?

The documentation says <kbd>⌥⏎</kbd> (<kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd>).

Quoting:

> "If there's an error in the code, pressing <kbd>⌥⏎</kbd> (macOS), or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (Windows/Linux), can suggest options that will make the code compile."

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tips/alt-enter/

> I recently switched to programming on a Mac and I don't know any of the keyboard shortcuts for IntelliJ.

Here's a list: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/mastering-keyboard-shortcuts.html?keymap=secondary_macos